# Getting Operation Timed error if posting request to other ports rather than specified 6007 port in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

```
private static string GetWebResponseMsg(string URI, string jsonRequest, string method)
    {
        try
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = method;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonRequest))
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(jsonRequest);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            string _result = string.Empty;
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                _result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            LogAndNotify(method, URI, jsonRequest, ex);
            return _result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogAndNotify(method, URI, jsonRequest, ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the API available on the other ports than 6007? Why you want to post to other ports?

Comment: The api is available in other ports, other ports as in port 80 and 443. In production these will be used. And more over it is working in postman for 80 and 443 port but not via c# code

Comment: You mean the code and the postman runs on the same computer and but works only from the postman? you might need to verify the value of `URI` variable that is it not pointing to different environment.

Comment: No, if i hit the api deployed on 443 port from postman its working. If i hit the same api with the above writted code its not working for 443 port but working for 6007 port.